# Magento 2 - creating a Custom Attribute of type Boolean and assigning its default value to all the existing products in the DB

Tags: api, csv, magento2.2.2

I have created a custom Attribute for the Product which if type Boolean and set the default value as `Yes`.

When I try to fetch the newly created attribute through Rest API I am not able to get the attribute field in my response.

However if I update the product through CSV file and hit the API, I am able to get the custom attribute field in the response.

Is there any way where the custom attribute's default value(Yes/No) is applied directly to the products instead of updating through CSV file.

Comment: How many products do you have?